# Find with condition where boolean matches must be 'true'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a questions regarding implementation of a system that will send messages to subgroups of people held in a database.

The [potential] message Recipients are held in a table.  Each Recipient record has a set of column booleans indicating whether they are a member of a particular group or not: msg_group_1:boolean, msg_group_2:boolean, etc.  Recipients may belong to more than one group.

There is also a Message table, where each message record has a corresponding set of booleans for indicating which groups the message is intended for.

Then, when a new message is composed, the form includes a checkbox to indicate which groups the message is intended for.

To implement the Send, I then need to find all members of the Recipients table that belong to any of the groups that the new Message is intended for.

I can't use,

```
Recipients.find(:all, :conditions => ['msg_group_1 = ? OR msg_group_2 = ?', @message.msg_group_1, @message.msg_group_2])
```

...as this will match records where the booleans are equal, even if the pair are booleans are both false (obviously I only want cases where both flags are true).

Is there an efficient way to 'find' these using a SQL search, or some other Ruby on Rails trick that will obtain the matching records where both flags are true?

Thanks.

Comment: I had an answer that addressed this specific example, but then I realized what you're really doing here. The design is not ideal. Are you going to add a new column every time you need a new message group?

Comment: Yeah, I'm beginning to realise the design isn't ideal ;-)  That said, the number of message groups is small and fixed. Alternative design suggestions welcome.

Comment: "Each Recipient record has a set of column booleans indicating whether they are a member of a particular group" - sounds like one-to-many relationship, where Recipient belongs to MessageGroup and MessageGroup has many Recipients.

Comment: Thanks, I can [now] see how that type of design would make more sense in the long term - but how would it apply if a Recipient can be member of more than one group?  Would that require a join table type arrangement?

Comment: Yes, many-to-many relationships require join table.

Comment: Thanks, so assuming there's not an easy answer to my original question, feel free to answer the question as 'wrong design', and I'll accept it.  Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, This question has been open for 5 months at time of writing, and no-one has offered a solution so the 'answer' seems to be that this is not possible.